# WIA Leadtools SDK scan two pages but generate 1 images in output folder

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, scanning, leadtools-sdk

I am using WIA Demo `"C:\LEADTOOLS 19\Examples\DotNet\CS\WiaDemo"`
for scanning multiple documents(put two documents in scanner).
When I scanned two documents then it only saves
one document in output folder. During scanning it shows(scanning 1 and then scanning document 2 but output will be only 1 document in folder)

*Any idea, what am I missing ?*

[image: Screenshot of Scanning Process]

Note:

- If I scan these two documents with same scanner using its utility
  instead of Leadtools then it generate two images successfully.
- Generated image using Leadtools SDK only contain image of 1 document.
- I am using C#, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: TIF format can store multiple pages/images. One document does not mean you only have one scanned page inside that document

Comment: @SirRufo - I put two pages in scanner. (physical two pages). But in output folder there is only image file(with extension .tif). If I open this scanned image file then it shows content of one page only

Comment: Please perform a simple test: Scan two pages and check the file size of the generated tif. Then scan only the first page again and check that file size. How much does the size of both files differs?

Comment: @SirRufo - You are right :). Files size are different when I perform two test as you said. In 3rd test, I changed the filetype from .tif to .jpg and then it generated two files. Thx

Comment: Some image viewers only show the first page of the tif, in others you can navigate through the pages of the tif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, it appears you found the cause of the behavior. Our LEADTOOLS SDK is capable of saving single-page and multi-page files in dozens of different formats. If you want to check whether the saved TIFF file contains multiple pages, you can see its file info using our main demo. To do that, use the File => Open dialog box, click on the image file then click the "info" button at the top right corner of the dialog. This should tell you the file's format and how many pages it has.

[image]